# Inconvenience about definition of the 1 to 1 function

Tags: functions, definition

I read a from my discrete mathematic book (Discrete Mathematics and Its Application), 
 Definition of the 1 to 1 function is

$( ∀a,∀b( f(a) = f (b) → a = b)$ 
 the problem of this statement is

if $f(a) \neq\ f(b)$   and $a = b$ it means that same numbers have different images and

it violates the definition of the function.

I think my definition would be more correct. which is

> $f(A):$ $f(a) = f(b)$  $ \iff  a = b $

Can you explain to me why I am correct or incorrect?

Comment: Not more correct, but equivalently correct.  Note that the adjective "1 to 1" (or synonymously *injective*) is (to the best of my knowledge) reserved for functions, as opposed to mere mappings.  On that basis, it is understood that $a = b \implies f(a) = f(b).$  That is, the function maps each element in the domain to exactly 1 value in the range.

Comment: How can it be equivalently correct? I use if and only if and the book just book use **implies**. And can you a little bit expand your answer? What does it mean to be opposed to mere mappings

Comment: If it is understood (or assumed) that statement $P$ implies statement $Q$, then the following two statements *become* equivalent, under the assumption: $Q \implies P$ and $Q\iff P$.  If you have a mapping from set $D$ to set $R$ (i.e. domain and range), one of the elements in the domain may map to more than one element in the range.  If (instead), you impose the constraint that the mapping is a **function**, then the above scenario is outlawed.

Comment: I understand it perfectly. Then let's say that we have no information about f is a function. We know f is a relation. So we can say that my definition of function f says that f is a 1 to 1 function. Is it correct?

Comment: We are getting into a set theory area where I am ignorant.  My understanding, which may be mistaken, is that the adjective "1 to 1" is reserved for functions.  That is, the adjective is not normally applied to mere mappings, which are not functions.  Assuming that my understanding is accurate, then (as I originally said) the two definitions are equivalent, for the reason that I detailed at the start of my last comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alternate definition is correct.
The usual definition is (as you said)
$$
\forall a, \forall b (f(a)=f(b) \Rightarrow a=b)
\tag1$$
The converse
$$
\forall a, \forall b (f(a)=f(b) \Leftarrow a=b)
\tag2$$
is true for every function.
Your alternative definition
$$
\forall a, \forall b (f(a)=f(b) \Leftrightarrow a=b)
\tag3$$
is true if and only if both $(1)$ and $(2)$ are true.  If we know in advance that $f$ is a function, this means that $(1)$ and $(3)$ are either both true or both false.

---

Both definitions are correct.  So we cannot say one is "more correct" than the other.  If we know in advance that $f$ is a function, then $(1)$ is easier to prove than $(3)$, which may explain why $(1)$ is usually given as the definition.

Comment: So when we say that f is a function. We already eliminate the option **f(a) and (b)** are not equal and **a and b** is equal. Do we already know that?